# Css3 animation doesn't work on firefox (background faded)

Tags: html, css

I wrote animation of changing background and it work every browser besides firefox. On FF background is changing but without animation effect.  I tried out `@-webkit-keyframes` but it didn't helped.
Thats the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/tkw5pfm8/

Answer (score 1):

`background-image` fade animation in FF is really disables. You will have to use separate `div`s with `background-image` for that

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.background>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide1 {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569__340.jpg);
  animation: fade 8s infinite;
}

.slide2 {
  background-image: url(https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/246/739/689/digital-digital-art-artwork-illustration-abstract-hd-wallpaper-thumb.jpg);
  animation: fade2 8s infinite;
}

.slide3 {
  background-image: url(https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/c/5/3/34778.jpg);
  animation: fade3 8s infinite;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes fade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='background'>
  <div class='slide1'></div>
  <div class='slide2'></div>
  <div class='slide3'></div>
</div>
```

Or better, use some simple JS slider, like Swiper

https://swiperjs.com/demos/#fade_effect